# PhoneGap Create Script Error

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I was following the setup guide, which is found [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) but when I run the create script, I get:

`An error occurred. Deleting project...`

My `bash_profile` file looks like this:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into shell session *as a function*

export PATH=${PATH}:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/tools
```

When I run `./bin/create ~/Desktop/myapp com.myapp.special MyApp` I get:

`An error occurred. Deleting project...`

(I don't have a folder `Desktop/myapp`)

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall the platform-tools to get it to work.